# How can I store the repeating css values in varialbles to make the code less repetitive?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

```
  $('ul#range-drop li#product1')
    .css( {backgroundPosition: '-914px 0px'} )
    .mouseover(function(){
      if (!($('ul#range-drop li#product1 a').hasClass("current")) ) {
        $(this).css( {background: "none"} );
        $(this).parent().stop().animate({backgroundPosition: '-914px -12px' }, {duration:400, easing: 'easeInOutQuint'});
      }
   })

  .mouseout(function(){
   $(this).parent().stop().animate({backgroundPosition : '-914px 0px'}, {duration:400, easing: 'easeInOutQuint'});
   });
```

This block of code repeats for each navigation element with different values for background positions

Comment: You can just create a function. Or there's somthing I've missed in your question?

Answer (score 0):

Put this code into a function where the input parameters are the name of the element id you want to bind the code to, the background positions, and any other changing information. Then you can just have one line (the method call) for each element, but the heart of the code is only written once.

For example (just threw this together, didn't test it)

```
applyCSS('ul#range-drop li#product1', -194, 0)

function applyCSS(id, posx, posy)
{
  $(id)
    .css( {backgroundPosition: posx + 'px ' + posy + 'px'} )
    .mouseover(function(){
      if (!($(id).hasClass("current")) ) {
        $(this).css( {background: "none"} );
        $(this).parent().stop().animate({backgroundPosition: posx + 'px ' + posy + 'px'},     {duration:400, easing: 'easeInOutQuint'});
      }
   })

  .mouseout(function(){
   $(this).parent().stop().animate({backgroundPosition: posx + 'px ' + posy + 'px'},     {duration:400, easing: 'easeInOutQuint'});
   });

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should store the values either in a `data-` attribute, or in a JavaScript map;

```
var map = {
  product1 : ['-914px 0px', '-914px -12px']
}

$('ul#range-drop li').each(function() {
    $(this).css('backgroundPosition', map[this.id][0]);
}).mouseover(function() {
    if (!($(this).hasClass("current"))) {
        $(this).css({
            background: "none"
        });
        $(this).parent().stop().animate({
            backgroundPosition: map[this.id][1]
        }, {
            duration: 400,
            easing: 'easeInOutQuint'
        });
    }
}).mouseout(function() {
    $(this).parent().stop().animate({
        backgroundPosition: map[this.id][0]
    }, {
        duration: 400,
        easing: 'easeInOutQuint'
    });
});​
```

The map contains the default background position as the first element in the array, and the animated position as the second (although of course, you can change this as you please, it's just an idea to get you started).

Answer (score 0):

```
    $('ul#range-drop li#product1')
        .css( {backgroundPosition: '-914px 0px'} )
        .mouseover(function(){
          if (!($('ul#range-drop li#product1 a').hasClass("current")) ) {
            $(this).css( {background: "none"} );
           animation($(this),"-12");
          }
       })
          .mouseout(function(){
      animation($(this),"0")
       });

function animation(obj,valu)
{       obj.parent().stop().animate({backgroundPosition : '-914px '+valu+'px'}, {duration:400, easing: 'easeInOutQuint'});
}
```